# Sum of digits of $1000^{20}-20$ in decimal notation

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

Find the sum of the digits of $$1000^{20}-20$$  written in decimal notation.

What exactly do they mean by decimal notation? How will the answer be any different if it is not in decimal form?

Comment: Well firstly, note that this is a power of $10$, and therefore, it will be in the form $10000000...$. So the sum of digits is just $1$!

Comment: "Decimal notation" means the base-10 notation that we usually use, as opposed to binary notation or Roman numerals or hexadecimal (base 16) expressions and the like.

Comment: write 10 in base 9, then turn into base 10 and square it, you'll see the difference when base is not decimal (decimal means base 10)

Comment: I agree, it's a bit cryptic.  I mean, nobody would have even thought of converting the result into some alternate base if they hadn't alluded to the possibility.

Comment: @ThomasRussell.Thanks!!! But the question is 1000^20-20.....How do u solve it ??(sorry!I made a typo)

Comment: Noting the revised question:  have you tried anything?  suppose the number were $10^4-20$.  Could you do it then?  What about $10^9-20$?  Can you spot a pattern?

Comment: @lulu...so the pattern would be like:10^4-20=9980,10^10-20=9999999980....so in 10^20-20 there would be 18 nines and 80 in the last two digits....am I right?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget your number is $10^{60}-20$.

Comment: @lulu...oh yeah right .....58 nines and  80?

Comment: @lulu I wouldn't be so sure that _nobody_ would consider alternate bases. The likelihood is slightly reduced due to the fact that it's so much easier to do in base ten, but I think the pre-emptive strike against that objection is at least somewhat justified.

Comment: @DavidK  To be fair...my comment (and all of the early comments) concerned the pre-edit version of the question, which just asked the sum of the digits in $1000^{20}$.  Of course the answer to that question is base-independent.

Answer (score 1):

$(10^n)^m =10^{nm}$
and this is,
in decimal,
a one followed by
$nm$ zeroes,
so the sum of the digits
is one.

Comment: Thanks...I made a mistake in the question.....it is 1000^20 - 20....sorry

Answer (score 1):

Note that in base $10$,

$$1000^{20}-20=10^{60}-20=999\ldots9980$$

so the trick in base $10$ is simply to figure out how many nines there are before the $80$.  This is easiest to do by first considering a few smaller exponents:

$$\begin{align}
10^3-20&=980\\10^4-20&=9980\\10^5-20&=99980
\end{align}$$

which suggests there are $60-2=58$ nines in $10^{60}-20$, so that the sum of the digits in $1000^{20}-20$ is $58\cdot9+8+0=530$.

My guess is that whoever wrote the problem added "written in decimal form" just to emphasize they were talking about the usual way we work with numbers.  If you want to pose the problem for some other base, you need to somehow specify whether the expression $1000^{20}-20$ is already written in the other base (which presumably could not be base $2$, since it uses the three digits $0$, $1$, and $2$) or if it needs to be converted from decimal to the other base.

Answer (score 1):

The result will have $60$ digits.
$\underbrace{99\dots9}_{58 \text { times}}80$.
$\text{Sum of digits}= (9\times58)+8+0= 530$.
$\text{In decimal notation}= 5.3\times10^2$.